# Angular Component view Inheritance

Tags: angular, templates, inheritance, view, components

I'm using angular4 since few month now, and I'm trying to figure out, how can I build inheritance between component.

So in my exemple I have two component ***ParentComponent*** and ***ChildComponent***

**ParentComponent.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css']
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  public makeSomeMath(a: number, b: number) {
    return a + b;
  }

}
```

**ParentComponent.html**

```
<p>I'm parent component</p>
```

**ChildComponent.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ParentComponent } from '../parent/parent.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent extends ParentComponent implements OnInit {

  public data: number;

  constructor() {
    super();
   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data = this.makeSomeMath(5, 6);
  }

}
```

**ChildComponent.html**

```
I'm child component and my result is : {{data}}
```

Here it's work, I'm using the ParentComponent function in the child and display the result in my template.

```
I'm child component and my result is : 11
```

I can override this behavior in my childComponent.ts :

```
public makeSomeMath(a: number, b: number) {
    return a - b;
}
```

And my result on the child component will be (with the same parameter as previous) :

```
I'm child component and my result is : -1
```

***So inheritance for the component behavior works fine, but what if, in my child component I wanted to use the Parent view ?***

I could change the *templateUrl* of my child component to use the parents one. But first, I don't know if it's best practice (I would have say no).
Second, If my template have (for exemple) 300 lines of Html, and I want to modify only few lines for my child component, I will have to change it in parent template and I don't whant that.

So my question is : How can I setup my template / component, to be able to do this 3 things :

- *Use the parent view without modification.*
- *Use the parent view with some modification.*
- *Override the whole view.*

Something like ng-content will be ok (unless there is something better) if I can use it with inheritance like defining some parts in the parents with a "default view" but if I use a ng-container in the child with the good ID, it will use this to replace the default content of the parent view.

If you have any hint for me, I would appreciate that, Thanks

Comment: If your parent template has 300 odd lines I feel it is a lengthy template design, I had searched about the same problem a few days back. I stumbled upon rewriting parent copied HTML into my child and modify that per my wish, I don't think view level inheritance can be achieved in Angular 4. If your parent is large I would suggest you break it into logical sub entities and then use it in your child. This way you will be able to maintain a lot of code re-usability and modularity.

Comment: Honestly I think inheritance is the wrong move here. Probably the best way to achieve this is by using ngTemplateOutlet https://alligator.io/angular/reusable-components-ngtemplateoutlet/ and then using the "ParentComponent" in the ChildComponent. If you need to modify anythign you can pass a template in the ChildComponent to the ParentComponent. Otherwise you can define a default in the parent. The article descibes the process of doing that quite well.

Comment: You can also have a Uniq html and use *ngIf

Comment: Thanks for your answers.The problem with breaking my comp in smaller piece it's if I have a view with a list of object and a music player, lets say that depending of the codec of the sound that is selected I want to render a part of this player differently, in my player view I should have a switch that say, if it's mp3, display that, if it's wave .... That mean each time I add a new Codec I should modify this Component. Now imagine in this component I have multiple parts to modify depending on the codec.... This component will be full of condition for each cases. It doesn't seems good to me.

Comment: I will look at your link Shadowlauch

Comment: I looked at your link, even if it's not really what I was looking for. But because what I was looking for seems to not exist. I will go for it ! Thanks